# Memory of the Contacts on iPhone?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, contacts

I want to ask a question about the Contacts on objective C. I am writing a program which will add the people to the iPhone build-in Contacts by ABPerson. However, I don't know I can add how many users to the iPhone. Are there some limitations of adding the contacts to the address book? I mean the number of user, adding field or the memory using/management. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**.  I've read user reports 10,000 contacts or more.  As long as your code doesn't leak, you should be just fine.  Return with a more specific question if you encounter any problems.

Comment: thank you for your reply. And I have another question is the size of the array. I use the array to store the data of the user (include the username, phone, email..) But I found that there are limitation of the array size (e.g. array[200]), and before running the program, I will not know how many user will add to the array. Is it possible to use the dynamic array to handle this problems? If it is possible, would you provide the code to me as I don't know how to create the dynamic array. Thank you.

Comment: You're looking for an `NSMutableArray`.  Search Apple documentation and StackOverflow for the term and you'll find more and better information than anyone could provide in a comment.